# dynamic layout based on dynamic data in android

Tags: java, android, layout, android-widget, widget

i need to get some json data from a server and then create elements to show that data. due the data is into an array of objects, i need to put this code into a loop.

example:

---

name - address

### save button

name - address

### save button

name - address

### save button

i am thinking to create an array of linearlayouts with the needed widgets inside and repeat this process n times.

am i going right? it would be great if you can help me with a point of view.

kind regards and thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a ViewGroup, then add each child view to that. The reason for this is it is more flexible (as the LinearLayout inherits from the ViewGroup). Then you can loop through each view later to get their values if need be

Answer (score 0):

no, you should use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) and put your data in an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). There are lots of examples and tutorials for that.